# Trying to get CSS switcher to work with ASP.NET rendered check-box

Tags: html, asp.net, css, vb.net

I'm trying to get CSS Switches to work with ASP.NET rendered check-box.

The way that CSS Switcher structured and the ASP.NET check-box rendered make it hard to me to get it work and the problem not only in the span generated around the input it's also the label - which I need for sure - for the check-box, once I remove them from rendered HTML it works.

ASP.NET Check-box adds span and label when rendered as follow:

```
<span>
    <input id="ID" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="ID"></input>
    <label for="ID">Label</label>
</span>
```

While the switcher needs the input to be wrapped in the following form:

```
<label class="switch switch-default">
    <input type="checkbox" checked><span></span>
</label>
```

[Here is an Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FA47K/)

here is how my check-box coded in my ASP HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
   <label class="switch switch-default"><asp:CheckBox id="chkAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass=""></asp:CheckBox><span></span></label>
</div>
```

Is there any workaround this problem?

Comment: Just put in your own markup in place of the default Webforms controls. Are you generating this markup from the server?

Comment: I'm not sure of your question but I'm using user-control contains the markup that has the form and running it my local windows7 IIS. The code I used above copied from Firefox inspector :)

Comment: Here is how it appears after rendering my asp http://jsfiddle.net/FA47K/1/

Comment: If you want your html to stay clean to the plugin's docs, don't use the ASP controls. Instead, use regular html structures and just add runat="server" to any element that you need to gain access to on the server side although you can also use  Request.Form to grab elements Those asp: tags are controls that can emit some foul html.

Comment: Thanks .. I have found a way .. posted below

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution and wanted to share.

As appears in  [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/43xyN/1/) which uses code similar to ASP.NET rendered check-boxes, the problem was with the CSS selectors and how to reach a parent that has a child check-box with checked or unchecked .. that is not applicable still in CSS. I had to add a jQuery function and change the selectors in my CSS to reach [this jsFiddle result](http://jsfiddle.net/43xyN/2/)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.switch input').each(function () {
           var _span = $(this).closest('.switch').children('span.sw-inner');
           if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(_span).addClass('checked').removeClass('un-checked');
            } else {
                $(_span).addClass('un-checked').removeClass('checked');
            }
        });
        $('.switch input').change(function () {
            var _span = $(this).closest('.switch').children('span.sw-inner');
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(_span).addClass('checked').removeClass('un-checked');
            } else {
                $(_span).addClass('un-checked').removeClass('checked');
            }
        });
 });
```